# SQL Server : GETDATE with Between function doesnt return the desired data

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

I am trying to show banner on page if dates is between `StartDate AND EndDate`

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
```

This fails to get record with ID 3 if I use `GETDATE()` which also compares datetime let since my time value is always `00:00:00.000` is there a way I can only use `GETDATE` to compare yyy-mm-dd part of database column so that above query will show all three records

```
 ID  StartDate                  EndDate
-------------------------------------------------------
  1  2020-12-31 00:00:00.000    2021-03-15 00:00:00.000
  2  2020-12-31 00:00:00.000    2021-03-31 00:00:00.000
  3  2021-01-01 00:00:00.000    2021-02-28 00:00:00.000
```

I also use below query but it showed same result set.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND CONVERT(varchar, EndDate, 23))
```

Changes datatype to store only date part can solve the issue but I can't make changes to database

Comment: `CONVERT(varchar, EndDate, 23))` Surely you know by now that this is a bad habit and lazy coding. ALWAYS specify an appropriate length for variable-length datatypes.

Comment: @Smor Converting dates to varchar in order to strip time part is also lazy

Comment: @Charlieface Yes it is both but we don't always have the luxury of a properly designed table.

Comment: @SMor What, that wasn't what I was saying. OP already has `date` columns, why convert them to `varchar` in order to strip the time, use `cast(... as date)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore times, do so on the `GETDATE()`:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

Or add a day to `EndDate` and use:

```
WHERE GETDATE() >= StartDate AND
      GETDATE() < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate)
```

Comment: The latter clause, with `DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate)` won't be SARGable, so I suggest against that solution.

Comment: @Larnu . . . The whole expression is not sargable.  I mean, an index could be used on one of the columns but that is probably of little benefit for this type of task -- and an index on `startDate` could still be used.

Comment: Yes it is sargeable `WHERE GETDATE() >= StartDate AND CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime) <= EndDate` would work fine. Although I question why the two columns are `datetime` anyway

Comment: The first solution *is* SARGable, Gordon.

Comment: Sargable - yes - but [might not be a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: @Charlieface, Columns have been defines as date time so that in future if banner are also showed based on time. So i want to keep all teh login in SQL SP just in case if we have to change so change will only be in SP not in the application

Comment: @SMor `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` has no effect on SARGability. It would be `CONVERT(date, {some column})` that would.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the query sarge-able (able to use indexes), convert `GETDATE` to how you want it, instead of converting the column.

```sql
WHERE
    GETDATE() >= StartDate AND
    CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime) <= EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```